# Who is authorized to access my application with Google's OAuth 2 client?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I developed a web application that uses the Google's OAuth 2.0 client and it works fine.

Well, let's say that my web application is published on Internet and everyone can open it using the browser (http://my-cool-web-app.cxx), see the "OAuth consent screen"...

[image]

...press `[Accept]` and get access for use my web app.

My question is: **how can I know who sign up to my web application?** Let's say that I have 5000 new users. How can I know who are they? How can I manage them, give them roles, etc.?

Is there any "Google User Accounts Management Console" anywhere? Do I have to write a new web app that be able to access to the Google API using my client ID and secret key to know who sign up?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Google OAuth 2.0 is letting the "app" access the user's google information not to access your app.

Comment: You're right. Thank you. More information, here ==> https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/wiki/Authentication-flows#ui-authentication-stateful--indirect-client

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't read your question fully. 
I don't think google have anything for you to see who access your web app. Not that I know of. It doesn't have access control to an external web app as well. It does however have user control on their own app.

With that said, I think you'll have to design your own database and access control on your web app. You can use google api to ID your user by getting their account information through OAuth 2 and use that as the base for your manage of users system under your app. Maybe set something up with group and base access on that.